# Move all Images in website down half their height

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

We have a website with many math formulas (displayed as pngs, converted from Latex) and they are dynamically loaded into their respective places (out of an sql-database).

All the formulas lie on line with the text. you know in this line: `_______________`.

We would like to have a function to take every element of a certain class (or by using "img" in css) with which we could automatically move all imgs down half of the respective image-height.

Is there a simple solution I'm overlooking, or do we really have to position every image (sadly, there will be hundreds!) by hand?

Comment: The way the question is worded looks like it must be harder than I think, but the way I'm seeing it, it looks like you want the images middle-aligned instead of sticking up? Why not just use `vertical-align: middle`? An example of the current and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pure Javascript Solution:**

```
//All of your images with class : class
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("class");

//Iterates through each of the images
for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    //Sets the images top margin to the half of the height of the image
    images[i].style.marginTop = images[i].style.height / 2;
}
```

**jQuery Solution:**

If [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is an option, you could use the the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to interate through each of them at set their heights accordingly:

```
$('.class').each(function()
{
    //Get Item Height
    var height = $(this).height();

    //Move Item Down By Half of Height
    $(this).css('margin-top',height/2);
});
```

More concise:

```
$('.class').each(function(){
    $(this).css('margin-top',($(this).height()/2));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Rionmonster! We aren't using jQuery yet, but this might be reason enough to plug it in. I'll check it out, thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't get to test it - hope it works. If not, let me know and I'll help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: I just noticed your Javascript code above and am playing around with it. but shouldn't the array be called "images" and not "menus"? (as in menus[i].style.) Other than that, this looks very nice. When using "getElementByTagName" and not ClassName, i should be even better off (for now, while testing and no other images are around). it would be a pain adding a class to every sing <img>. thanks though, great help!

Comment: Np - I had copied the code over from a different location and usage, forgot to change everything :) Edited it to reflect the updated changes.

Answer (score 0):

What Rionmonster said except that I'd add that to get the height (or any dimension) of an image I have always had to say:

```
theHeight = parseFloat( element.style.height );
```

parseFLoat( ) because it will handle anything parseInt( ) can handle, while the reverse is not true.